# Select and Where on multiple (sequential range) of criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm looking for an SQL solution for my sheet that looks exactly 28 columns deep into a row, and if it has any non-blank values in that range, retrieves it.

Currently I'm able to get exactly what i want using this horrible formula:

```
QUERY(SomeOtherSheet!A85:BA,"select A,B,C,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z where (O>=0 OR P>=0 OR Q>=0 OR R>=0 OR S>=0 OR T>=0 OR U>=0 OR V>=0 OR W>=0 OR X>=0 OR Y>=0 OR Z>=0) ",1)
```

suffice to say the range O-Z isn't exactly 28 long, but its enough to showcase what I'm looking for in this example.

Question) Is there a better way to achieve this kind of query on a sequential range of columns? 
specifically in my case the range of O-AQ

I suppose i can dynamically string together in a different cell the cols required. But I'd rather not...

Comment: I don't think there's any other way except stringing the text together

Comment: @pnuts not exactly what I've been looking for, but have sparked an idea that might lead to a true dynamic answer! i'll post here if im done before anyone else answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know OP already answered. But submitting this as an alternative:

For the Select,

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",",CHAR(ROW(65:90)),"A"&CHAR(ROW(65:90))))
```

For the where OR part:

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(">=0 OR ", CHAR(Row(65:90)),"A"&CHAR(ROW(65:90))))&">=0"
```

To change the start and end parts, change the ROW number start and end parts:

http://www.asciitable.com

Answer (score 1):

Please try converting the range into array:

`QUERY({SomeOtherSheet!A85:BA},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,...")`

I always use this method and search for columns inside query by their index, e.g. look for column called "Name":

`=match("Name", SomeOtherSheet!A85:BA85, 0)`

---

**Update**. To combine `OR` part of query:

`="where Col"&JOIN(" >= 0 or Col",ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(O1:Z1)))&" >= 0"`

The result is:

`"where Col15 >= 0 or Col16 >= 0 or Col17 >= 0 or Col18 >= 0 or Col19 >= 0 or Col20 >= 0 or Col21 >= 0 or Col22 >= 0 or Col23 >= 0 or Col24 >= 0 or Col25 >= 0 or Col26 >= 0"`

If new columns will be pasted inside range `O1:Z1` this formula will adjust. In real projects it's useful to find ranges by their points: start cell, last cell and then use `indirect`:

`="where Col"&JOIN(" >= 0 or Col",ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(indirect(range))))&" >= 0"`

where `range` is name of range with string "O1:Z1", "O1" and "Z1" are found by their column names or ids.

Comment: Won't this make everything longer? Instead of `where (O>=0 OR P>=0 OR Q>=0 OR R>` We'll be doing  : `"("&MATCH ("O",A85:BA85,0)&">=0 "& MATCH ("P".....` I fail to see a application here... Could you explain a bit more or give a example where you use this

Comment: @pnuts, answered in Edit

Comment: @anonymous, answered in Edit

Comment: Nice trick. By converting to array we only have to deal with numbers, therefore the entire parsing part of the question is averted. I've taken note of this method, although it doesn't perfectly do what i need. (since adding new rows will auto-expand the range, whereas in my very specific situation i want to always start at X and go 28 cols deep)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've worked out how to dynamically concatenate a string with as few possible static magic numbers:

First, A cell that contains:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula((IF((COLUMN(Lifetime!N$8:$8)+64)>CODE("Z"),"A"&CHAR(MOD(COLUMN(Lifetime!N$8:$8),26)+64),""&CHAR(COLUMN(Lifetime!N$8:$8)+64)))),1,28)
```

which gives us the following array:

```
N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO
```

this array can be used for the Select part of the query easily.
I've allowed myself the freedom of not accounting for cells that will be B* since my personal sheet won't get there. The `Array_constrain()` column parameter allows for quick change to different size of arrays if ever needed in the future.

Secondly, a simple `textjoin()` + `regexreplace()` for the required where clause

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A119:AB119),",",">=0 OR ")&">=0"
```

which results in the required string for the where clause:

```
N>=0 OR O>=0 OR P>=0 OR Q>=0 OR R>=0 OR S>=0 OR T>=0 OR U>=0 OR V>=0 OR W>=0 OR X>=0 OR Y>=0 OR Z>=0 OR AA>=0 OR AB>=0 OR AC>=0 OR AD>=0 OR AE>=0 OR AF>=0 OR AG>=0 OR AH>=0 OR AI>=0 OR AJ>=0 OR AK>=0 OR AL>=0 OR AM>=0 OR AN>=0 OR AO>=0
```

And the final product:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(Lifetime!A85:BA,"select A,B,C,"&120&" where ("&A121&")",1),105,20)
```

or as a one-liner:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula((IF((COLUMN(Lifetime!N$8:$8)+64)>CODE("Z"),"A"&CHAR(MOD(COLUMN(Lifetime!N$8:$8),26)+64),""&CHAR(COLUMN(Lifetime!N$8:$8)+64)))),1,28)),",",">=0 OR ")&">=0"
```

Comment: > I suppose i can dynamically string together in a different cell the cols required. But I'd rather not..   
I did come up with something like this.. but you said no different cell...

Comment: `=JOIN(">=0 OR ",ARRAYFORMULA(CHAR(ROW (A65:A90))))`  `=ARRAYFORMULA("A"&JOIN(" A",CHAR(ROW(65:90))))`

Comment: almost perfect! if you've a way to combine the two so as to create the `>= OR ` on the entire range that might be a much less complex solution

Comment: Submitted an answer. Check it out.